# how to view pdf file in jsp

Tags: java, jsp-tags

i want view pdf file just view dynamically in pop up window using java.while i clicking that file link open a pdf file pop up window its don't allow down load option please help me give some example in java.i need need java code with using action to jsp

```
File f= new File(file);
if(f.exists()){
ServletOutputStream op= response.getOutputStream();
response.reset();
if(check==1){
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
}else{
response.setContentType(content);
          }
// response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" +fileName);
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int length;
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)){
op.write(buf,0,length);
                }
in.close();
op.flush();
op.close();
}
```

Comment: you want to open the pdf document in your browser or you want to display it in a frame?

Answer (score 0):

To open the local file you need to use the file scheme in your URL

As you path is a Windows path E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf, the link's href needs file:/// added before the your jsp's <%=path%> variable, so that the browser knows it needs to open a local file on the user's machine.

So your link should look like this

">click here
 Which in your browser will resolve to file:///E:/files/IT/cat1/cat1Notification.pdf

Without the file scheme the browser assumes that your link is relative to the webpage and tries to resolve the link by making a request to your webapp.